# SQL query passing table to stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, parameters

I have list of DateTime values, and for each value I need to fetch something from the database. I would like to do this with one query. I know it's possible to pass a table (list) to the stored procedure, but I'm not sure how to write the query itself.

Let's say I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Shows(
    ShowId [int] NOT NULL, 
    StartTime DateTime NOT NULL, 
    EndTime DateTime NOT NULL 
)
```

and an array of dates

```
DECLARE @myDateArray MyCustomDateArrayType
```

Now, if I were fetching a single item, I would write a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Shows
WHERE StartTime > @ArrayItem and @ArrayItem < EndTime
```

where @ArrayItem is an item from @myDateArray .

But how do I formulate the query that would fetch the information for all array items?

Comment: I think you meant `StartTime <= @ArrayItem`.

Comment: What database are you using? MySQL? Oracle? MS SQL Server? Something else? The answer will be specific to what you are using, as each RDBMS has different features.

Comment: what do you mean for all array items - as one row could well only fit the query for some of the array not all - should it be included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM Shows s
    JOIN @MyDateArray t ON s.StartTime > t.TableVarDateField 
        AND t.TableVarDateField < s.EndTime
```

Comment: How do you know he is using SQL Server?

Comment: @Oded - I may be wrong, but it sounds very much like OP is talking about Table Valued Parameter suport in SQL Server 2008 - I don't know of mySQL or Oracle supporting the same in the manner they've described (but I'm by no means an expert on those).

Comment: Yes, I'm using SQL server.

Anyway, answer suggested by AdaTheDev works great! I didn't realize that was SQL Server related syntax...

Thanks guys!